# How to calculate the mean curvature of clifford torus immersed in the standard sphere $\mathbb{S}^3$?

Tags: differential-geometry, minimal-surfaces

We know that clifford torus is a minimal surface immersed in $\mathbb{S}^3$, but how to express this immersion in parametrization and how to calculate the mean curvature of this immersion? If anyone can help me, thanks very much!

Comment: The Wikipedia article has a good explanation of what it is. It would be good to know what you’ve tried so far and what you know about calculating the mean curvature.

Comment: @Deane I searched in Wikipedia and there says that "It is easy to verify that the Clifford torus is a minimal surface in $S^3$" without giving any references. I know how to calculate the mean curvature of a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$, but I have no idea about the case that the ambient space is $\mathbb{S}^3$. Could you help me?

Comment: Are you familiar with using moving frames with differential forms?

Comment: @Deane Yes, I am familiar with moving frames!

Comment: See if you can set up an orthonrmal frame along the torus where the first two vectors are tangent, the third is tangent to the sphere, and the fourth is normal to the sphere. Then do the calculations with the dual 1-forms as you normally would. Post here whatever you manage to get, and I or others can guide you further.

Comment: @Deane Thanks! I'll try!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is absolutely no need to parametrize the Clifford torus to compute its mean curvature.
One only needs to find a normal vector field in $S^3$ and an orthonormal frame of its tangent bundle.
The Clifford torus $T$ is $T = \left\{(x_1,y_2,x_2,y_2)\in \Bbb R^4 \mid {x_1}^2+ {y_1}^2 = {x_2}^2 + {y_2}^2 = \frac{1}{2} \right\}$.
Consider the two vector fields $E_1$ and $E_2$ defined by
$$
E_1(x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2) = \sqrt{2}(-y_1,x_1,0,0) \quad \text{and} \quad E_2(x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2) = \sqrt{2}(0,0,-y_2,x_2).
$$
One readily checks that $\{E_1,E_2\}$ induces an orthonormal frame on $T$.
The vector fields
$$
N(x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2)=(x_1,y_1,-x_2,-y_2) \quad \text{and} \quad \bar{N}(x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2) = (x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2)
$$
are such that $\{E_1,E_2,N,\bar{N}\}$ is an orthonormal frame of $\iota^*(T\Bbb R^4)$ where $\iota\colon T\to \Bbb R^4$ is the inclusion.
Moreover, $\bar{N}$ is the normal vector field to $S^3$ in $\Bbb R^4$, and $N$ is the normal vector field to $T$ in $S^3$.

Let $W$ be the Weigarten map of $T\subset S^3$, defined by $W(X) = \nabla^{S^3}_X N$, where $\nabla^{S^3}$ is the Levi-Civita connection of $S^3$.
By definition, the mean curvature $H$ of $T\subset S^3$ is the trace of $W$, that is
$$
H = \langle W(E_1),E_1\rangle + \langle W(E_2),E_2\rangle.
$$
Recall that $\nabla^{S^3}$ is the orthogonal projection of the ambient directional derivative onto $TS^3 = \bar{N}^{\perp}$, so that for $i\in\{1,2\}$, one has $W(E_i)=\nabla^{S^3}_{E_i}N = D_{E_i}N - \langle D_{E_i}N,\bar{N}\rangle \bar{N}$.
From the expression of $N$, one has $D_{E_1}N = E_1$ and $D_{E_2}N = -E_2$.
(Coincidentally, these values have no component in the direction of $\bar{N}$: this is **not** a general fact.)
It follows that $W(E_1) = E_1$ and $W(E_2)=-E_2$.
Finally,
$$
H = \langle W(E_1),E_1\rangle + \langle W(E_2),E_2\rangle = \|E_1\|^2 - \|E_2\|^2 = 1-1 = 0.
$$
Note that we have shown more than the fact that $T$ is minimal in $S^3$: we have shown that its principal curvatures are $1$ and $-1$.

If one really wants to use a parametrization, then consider the one given by $f(s,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\cos s, \sin s, \cos t, \sin t)$.
One has $E_1 = \sqrt{2}\partial_s f$, $E_2 = \sqrt{2}\partial_t f$, *etc.*